# Clojure map outside scope

Tags: vector, file-io, clojure, hashmap

I am trying to save data into a collection of some sort, but the program that I have is saving everything into a separate map. I want to make it one map.

```
(defn readFile []
    (map (fn [line] (clojure.string/split line #";"))
      (with-open [rdr (reader "C:/Users/Rohil/Desktop/textfile.txt")]
        (doseq [[idx line] (map-indexed vector(line-seq rdr))]

          (if(.contains line "201609")
            (if(not(.contains line "TBA"))
              (println(assoc table :code(nth(clojure.string/split line #";")3) :instructor(nth(clojure.string/split line #";")19)))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `table`? Also `println` will return `nil` and `assoc` does _not_ **modify** any `(def table {})` you might have put somewhere before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are adapting to clojure :-) I went to the same process. Hang on, it will be worth it!

First: it is important to realize that map will save the result of the function into a new collection. Like cfrick mentions, `println` returns `nil` and assoc does not change a map.

I'm guessing a bit here what you are trying to do: You want to have a collection of dicts, where every dict has two keys, like so:

```
[
  { :code 1 :instructor "blah"} 
  { :code 2 :instructor "boo" }
]
```

You need these values to come from a file, but you only want to save the lines where the line contains "201609" but not "TBA"

First some general remarks:

- You probably want to split this function into smaller parts. One could be the check for lines (`contains 201609 but not tba` ), another could read the file...
- I know it is the title of your question, but most likely there is a better way than to change a global variable. Maybe you could make the function `readFile` return the table?
- try if you can pass in arguments to your function.
- I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the line `(doseq [[...` Please give us more context there. I will ignore it

Here is a possible solution:

```
(ns test
  (:require  [clojure.string :as s]
             [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn line-filter [include exclude line]
  (and (not (s/includes? line exclude))
       (s/includes? line include)))

(defn process-line [line]
  (let [line-parts (s/split line #";")
        code (nth line-parts 3)
        instructor (nth line-parts 19)]
    {:code code :instructor instructor}))

(defn read-file [file-name]
  (s/split (slurp (io/resource file-name)) #"\n"))

(defn parse-lines [lines] 
  (map process-line lines))


(defn read-file-and-parse
  "This function will read a file, process the lines, and output a collection of maps"
  [filename search-for exclude]
  (parse-lines
   (filter #(line-filter search-for exclude %)
    (read-file filename))))
```

you could now call this function like this: `(read-file-and-parse "test.txt" "201609" "TBA")`

If you want to add the result of this function into your `table`, you can use `concat`. But again, this will return a new version of your list (with new entries added) and not change the one you defined earlier.

Welcome to functional programming :-)))